# Delete entity relationship Coredata

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, relational-database

Using CoreData, I have a entity called Wishlist with a many to many relationship to entity call WishlistProduct.  (the relationship is called 'wishlists').

product.wishlists = nil  removes the relationship between Wishlist and WishlistProduct.  WishlistListProduct is referenced in multiple Wishlist and product.wishlists = nil removes all references, how can i remove the reference to a specific Wishlist

```
        WishlistProduct *product;

        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
        product.wishlists = nil;   //  Removes all relationships

         [context save:nil];
```

i thought something like currentWishlist.product.wishlists = nil,  any help would be great

Comment: Please edit your question.  As it stands right now, I am confused as to what you are trying to accomplish, and I can't even find a question that you are trying to get answered.

Comment: I've updated my question, does it make more sense now?

Comment: Why are you re-defining the context in every iteration of the loop? Clearly, the context outside the loop is a different context.

Comment: In general, if the model is important, you should take a picture of the model in the model editor, and post that.  Furthermore, your text above the code does not match the code because you are looping through each product and thus I really don't know what you are asking.  I still do not understand what your end goal is.  What is it that you are trying to do?  What code do you have that tries to accomplish your goal (the posted code seems to do something different from your goal)?  If your goal were more clearly stated, maybe you wouldn't need all of that, but to me your goal is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have a many-to-many relationship, you cannot refer to a specific product with `wishList.product` because you have *more than one* product per list.

You first have to filter/fetch the product in question and then you can set it's wish lists to `nil`.

Setting the to-many relationship (which is of type `NSSet`) of a particular `Product` to `nil` might do the trick, but you should test it. You should check if all the reverse relationships are also updated as expected. If that is not the case, loop through the lists and remove the product from the `products` relationship of each.

Actually, Xcode creates the proper accessors to add and remove to-many objects for you when you generate the `NSManagedObject` subclass. They look something like this

```
- (void)addListsObject:(List *)value;
- (void)removeListsObject:(List *)value;
- (void)addLists:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeLists:(NSSet *)values;
```

Comment: I have the product which I want to remove, the problem is the product is referenced in multiple wish lists and removing the relationship product.wishlists = nil; //wishlists is the name of the relationship. Removes all relationships.  I want to remove product relationship to a specific Wishlist

Comment: I understand. All cases are covered in my answer.

Comment: Ok Great thanks.  NSMutableOrderedSet *set = [self.wishlist.products mutableCopy];
        [set removeObject:product];
        self.wishlist.products = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithOrderedSet:set];

Comment: This isn't correct. Use mutableSetValueForKey or generated accessors.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get all whishlists of the product and remove the whishlist.

```
NSMutableSet *set = [product mutableSetValueForKey:@"wishlists"];
[set removeObject:wishlist];
```

or the other way around.

If you generated a subclass of NSManagedObject, you can use Core Data Generated Accessors.

```
[product removeWishlistsObject:wishlist];
```

or the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but here are examples for the four possibilities I can think of.

```
- (void)removeWishlist:(NSManagedObject*)wishlist
           fromProduct:(NSManagedObject*)product {
    [[product mutableToManyRelationshipForKey:@"wishlists"] removeObject:wishlist];
}

- (void)removeProduct:(NSManagedObject*)product
         fromWishlist:(NSManagedObject*)wishlist {
    [[wishlist mutableToManyRelationshipForKey:@"products"] removeObject:product];
}

- (void)removeAllProductsFromWishlist:(NSManagedObject*)wishlist {
    [wishlist setValue:nil forKey:@"products"];
}

- (void)removeAllWishlistsFromProduct:(NSManagedObject*)product {
    [product setValue:nil forKey:@"wishlists"];
}
```

Where `mutableToManyRelationshipForKey:` is a category method on `NSManagedObject` which returns the appropriate mutable collection based on whether the relationship is ordered or not.

```
- (id)mutableToManyRelationshipForKey:(NSString*)key {
    NSRelationshipDescription *relationship =
        [[self.entity relationshipsByName] objectForKey:key];
    return relationship.isOrdered
        ? [self mutableOrderedSetValueForKey:key]
        : [self mutableSetValueForKey:key];
}
```

Of course, all of this is a bit easier if you use the code generated by Xcode or something like mogenerator.